# How can anyone check a Tableau workbook on SonarQube or Lint?

Tags: sonarqube, tableau-api, talend

How can anyone check a Tableau workbook on SonarQube or Lint?

Making the question more generic -how can packaged codes like Talend jobs, Tableau workbooks be used and inspected for code quality in Sonarqube?

Thanks for any insight...!

Comment: Why do you think this is possible?

Comment: I may be mistaken but I believe Sonarqube is a tool for code quality. Tableau isn't programming code, it's a tool for visualizing data. You could argue that the xml in the twb and tds files are programming code but that's not the type of code that Sonarqube is used for. I guess you could put your workbooks and data sources under version control and attach Sonarqube but you won't be able to do much more than monitor pull requests or branch analysis. I would be interested though in some sort of quality tool to check changes to Tableau workbooks.